# WCF Authentication and Socket Aborted Exception

Tags: wcf, certificate, net.tcp

here's the setup for the project.

I have a WCF Service that is hosted on a net.tcp binding in buffered mode and ReliableSession enabled.

The binding is configured to use TransportWithMessageCredential security. The certificate is a self signed certificate that I am identifying using the Thumbprint. 
The UserNameValidator is a custom validator which for testing, never fails (it wasn't failing before but I removed the uncertainty)

The service and client are on the same machine and they both have access to the certificate.

The problem:

I am receiving a Socket Aborted exception when trying to consume a Method from the service. Here is the code I use to open a connection to the service. MonitorServiceCallbacks only contains empty methods to fulfil the requirements of the Interface.

```
 _instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new MonitorServiceCallbacks());
 _serviceInterface = new MonitorCallbackServiceClient(_instanceContext);

 _serviceInterface.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Environment.MachineName;
 _serviceInterface.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword";
 _serviceInterface.Open();
```

This appears to work fine as the _serviceInterface.State variable is set to State.Opened and the custom validator is called and returns without exception.

However, if I try to call a method using the _serviceInterface proxy, no code that I can break into is run on the service and the tracelog reveals no errors apart from a SocketAborted exception which occurs 1 minute after receiving what appears to be the message for the method.

There is no InnerException.

I have tried to google the issue but the results tend to say "just disable security and it will work fine". Unfortunately, this cannot be done.

I am extremely confused by this issue and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Ehrys

Comment: Hi WCF Tracing is turned on but as I indicated, it's not giving me any useful information.

The first exception that it receives is the SocketAborted exception. 
The trace level is set to Verbose, Activity Tracing, Propagate activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a serialisation error.

The object I was trying to send to the service inherited from the data contract. So I was trying to send a cast down to the data contract to the service.

WCF doesn't appear to allow this.

I would like to thank John Saunders for reminding me that not only the service can have tracing enabled. Enabling client side tracing would have saved me a lot of time.

I was attempting to do the following:

```
_serviceInterface.Register((MyDataContract)MyParentObject, aVariable, anotherOne);
```

What I needed to do:

```
MyDataContract tempContract = MyParentObject.CreateMyDataContract();
_serviceInterface.Register(tempContract, aVariable, anotherOne);
/* Note: MyParentObject.CreateMyDataContract() is my own method which creates an instance
of the MyDataContract and copies the relevant information to it */
```